# Retrieving map markers using Google Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have been trying to display the info window of a marker outside of a click event. I know you can do this using

```
marker.showInfoWindow();
```

My problem is getting the marker in the first place. I have tried something to the effect of:

```
Marker marker;

//then later
marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
             .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
             .title("Hello world"));

//then later
if (condition)
    marker.showInfoWindow();
```

To me this looks right but when I implement it no window appears. When I was debugging, it looked like the id of `marker` was different to the id of the "same" marker passed into `onMarkerClick(Marker marker)`

So either is there something I am missing OR is there a better way to retrieve the marker? (It doesn't seem to make sense that there isn't a method along the lines of `mMap.getMarkers()` or `mMap.findMarkerById()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awkwardly what I have here actually does work fine. My issue was that I had code critical to my `infoWindow` generation in my `onMarkerClick()` method and as such needed to pull it out of there into a method so I could call it in both places.

So any future googlers, my code is a solution of you need it - although you can probably work it out without googling